# Javascript filled field value $_POST's NULL?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I've got a form that I'd like to fill with Javascript. It works!

But when I submit the form, it doesn't validate, and it says that field is null.

If I fill in the form manually, it works just fine?

The form in question is [here](http://saveamillioncampaign.com/how-much-did-you-save/)

**EDIT**

Here's the JS for the form

```
$('#old').keyup(function () {
    if(this.value > 49){
        $('#new').val(this.value - 49);
        $('#new').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } else { 
        $('#new').val('0');
        $('#new').removeAttr('disabled');   
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the code to the question?

Comment: Disabled fields don't get submitted by the browser. If you're looking for their values in PHP, they won't exist.

Comment: I wish you'd have made that an answer, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabled fields don't get submitted by the browser. If you're looking for their values in PHP, they won't exist.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Francois' answer, you can use readonly instead of disabled.